Script en Putty como modificar el archivo con vi
¿Cómo se hacer para guardar cambios al modificar un archivo como este?
Utilice este comando:
sudo vi /config/scripts/pinger.sh

Pego las lineas del script pero no puedo guardar las modificaciones, al apretar ctrlD crea la linea ^D
Muchas gracias.

Bienvenido a [es.so], mira [ask] para entender como funciona el sitio. Aquí se responden preguntas de programación, y antes de preguntar suele estar bien buscar algo en internet. De todas formas, para salir del editor vi, basta con darle al escape para poner al editor en modo consola, y escribir :wq y darle a guardar. De esta manera se guarda y se sale del archivo. En caso de querer descartar, puedes poner :q!. Encontrarás el uso completo de vi aquí: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19620-01/805-7644/6j76klopr/index.html

En el editor vi o en vim tiene sus particularidades de uso. No es complicado, pero difiera de otros editores que hayas podido utilizar en que no hay menús y pocas cosas se hacen con la tecla de control: ctrlalgo.
Para realizar acciones, usualmente entras comandos, algunos de ellos precedidos por el símbolo de :.
En el caso de guardar el archivo, debes, primero, no estar en modo de edición sino en modo de comandos; sales del modo de edición presionando esc) y luego ingresas el comando :w (de write file).
:w

Tip pro: :wq escribe el archivo y cierra el editor. Evita tener que usar los comandos por separado.
Te recomiendo leer alguna introducción a vi, como esta en español: Editor VI o esta en inglés: An introduction to the vi editor y, mientras te acostumbras a su uso, puedes valerte de algún sitio u hoja que liste comandos habituales, tal como este vi cheat sheet.
Todos los recursos mostrados los encontré rápidamente en Google. VI está bien documentado y es más popular de lo que uno podría creer. Yo tengo más de 20 años usándolo de vez en cuando y no lo cambiaría por nada.
